# Error in OBJLoader of THREE.JS lilbrary

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to follow the examples in that book in order to learn the Three.js library "Learning Three.js: The JavaScript 3D Library for WebGL" and I also have the example sets downloaded from that github link https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs. Most of the examples are runing fine but some of them raises an error especially the one which loads Wavefront objects with OBJLoader.js file. It raises the following error in run time

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VM12649 OBJLoader.js:66`

Corresponding portion of OBJLoader.js is

```
function meshN( meshName, materialName ) {

        if ( geometry.vertices.length > 0 ) {

            geometry.mergeVertices();
            geometry.computeCentroids();   //EXCEPTION RASED HERE !!!!!
            geometry.computeFaceNormals();
            geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

            object.add( mesh );

            geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

            verticesCount = 0;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have downloaded the latest version of the three.js library (probably r68) but the examples are written against version r63 so somethings have changed.

As you can see at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases in r67 the method `computeCentroids` was removed from the `Geometry`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't notice that. Does that mean that we have to wait till the Jos Dirksen updates learning-threejs to conform with current release (r68)?

Comment: You have two options. Download the sample you want and convert it to r68 or if you want to see the sample running download the r63 version of three.js from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r63 (bottom of the page)