# Three JS object load, put a color to an object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to put an color to a object in three js.
Tried alot of different things but it didnt work.

```
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader.load("hoesje/hoesje.json", function ( object ) {
    scene.add( object );
});
```

I hope someone can help me out, thanks.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
    var object = event.content;
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
            child.material.color.setRGB (1, 0, 0);
    });
    scene.add( object );
});
loader.load( 'hoes.obj' );
```

but then I get this error : TypeError: loader.addEventListener is not a function

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( 'load', function ( event ) {
    var object = event.content;
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
            child.material.color.setRGB (1, 0, 0);
    });
    scene.add( object );
});
loader.load( 'hoes.obj' );
```

I did change .addEventListener to .load but it give me the follow error
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied

```
    var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader.load("hoesje/hoesje.json", function ( object ) {
scene.add( object );
} );
```

The code above is my working code to load an model in ThreeJS, in this code I would like to implent a function to change to color..any ideas?

Comment: Does the first portion of code work?

Comment: Yes the first the code I posted load the model in and shows it in the browser. I want to add a color to that object.

The second code does not work at all, it dont shows the model.

Comment: Why are you using an event listener on `loader` instead of one of the `OBJLoader` [methods](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/OBJLoader) like `.load()` like in the first working code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I dont know threejs but looking at your code and the issue seems to be the adding the event listener. Why not use the [methods](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/OBJLoader) that the `OBJLoader` has:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load('hoes.obj', function(object) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )
            child.material.color.setRGB (1, 0, 0);
    });
    scene.add( object );
})
```

**EDIT**
In responde to OP's edit. The `.load()` method:
`.load ( url, onLoad, onProgress, onError )`

> url — required
>   onLoad — Will be called when load completes. The
>   argument will be the loaded Object3D.
>   onProgress — Will be called
>   while load progresses. The argument will be the XmlHttpRequest
>   instance, that contain .total and .loaded bytes.
>   onError — Will be
>   called when load errors.

Given the code below
`loader.load( 'load', function ( event )`

`load` does not seem to be a `url`.
`function(event)` -- its not an event - its the loaded Object3D.
This is why in the answer above instead of creating an `eventListener` and then trying to trigger it, the `load()` method is called with the `.obj resource`.

Comment: I tried your code Craicerjack, I do get the follow error :
TypeError: geometry.computeCentroids is not a function
[Meer info]

Comment: Are you working off examples? This might be an issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322640/error-in-objloader-of-three-js-lilbrary

Comment: Yes I do work off an examples from Clara.io where u can download free models for threejs. I can load in the models but I dont get it to work to change a color of the model.

Comment: do u have any more ideas? would be great.

Comment: Well according to the linked question you could download the old version of three.js - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r63 or check whats triggering the error and try and fix that